# Are composites of serializable objects also serializable?

Tags: java, string, serialization, composite

If I have a serializable type e.g. `String` and make a class

```
class Tuple {

  String s1 = "Hello";
  String s2 = "World";

}
```

Then will this class also be serializable because both strings are, or will it not be serializable because it doesn't implement the serializable interface?

Comment: A big nooooooo..refer http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't. Class implementing `Serializable` interface can be serialized. Not a class having has-a relationship with `Serializable` class objects.

You may like to read about [Serializable here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/).

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure whether I must make it serializable though. Since it seems not a proof that the code can run in practice without the serialization since it might be deployed to another platform where the componenet are separated and then the transport will require serialization. So I suppose that I can't test whether I must serialize an object unless I know the separation between the components which might be different if the code is run in another anvironment where there is actual network transport and not on the same host and in-memory (RAM).

Answer (score 1):

No, your class must implement `Serializable` interface. Java does not make such bottom-to-top assumptions about the data.

```
class Tuple implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5316748056989930874L;

    //whatever
}
```